# Route elsewhere on navigate to route

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

With using the `React-Navigation`, to go to a specific page I would do this:

```
navigation.navigate('ProgramNav', {
  screen: "Programs"
});
navigation.navigate('ProgramNav', {
  screen: "Class List",
  params: {
    programId,
  }
});
navigation.navigate('ProgramNav', {
  screen: "Student Items",
  params: {
    programId,
    studentId,
  }
});
navigation.navigate('ProgramNav', {
  screen: "Student Item View",
  params: {
    programId,
    studentId,
    itemId
  }
});
```

So far, it hasn't been much of an issue, but what I want is to be able to make it so that when I navigate to the `"Programs"` screen, it checks if there is one program. If so, it navigates to the `"Class List"` with that one program automatically (ideally removing itself from the stack). **BUT** I want that logic to be in the `ProgramsScreen` component and not where I do the `navigation.navigate`.

I also want to make sure that when I hit `Back`, it will skip the Screen as well.

I am thinking it's something like `navigation.replace()` when there's something like a `useFocusEffect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with `useFocusEffect` and `replace` BUT it does an animation.  Is there a way of avoiding that animation?

```
  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
    if (programs.length === 1) {
      navigation.replace('Class List', {
        ...route.params,
        programId: programs[0].programID
      })
    }
  }, []))
```

To work around the animation issue at least when I navigate from the tab bar.  I had to create a new route and make that the new initial route such that if I navigate to the root page I would route to the proper one using `useFocuseEffect` as above and apply to the combinations leading up to the screen I need also returning `null` and `headerShown: false` to prevent showing any content.